# Why does the AWS-EC2 CPU utilization drops gradually while the same python script is running?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cpu

I have a python script running on Amazon Web Server. Initially the CPU utilization is high, ~60%. However it gradually drops to between ~0-1% rate and ranges around there while the same script runs. Why does this happen?

My python script is as follows:

```
`import numpy as np
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',100)
import scipy as sp
from sklearn import preprocessing as pp
import pickle
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV, LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import xgboost as xgb

pred = pd.read_pickle('./couple_data_lasso_feature_selection_predictors')
target = pd.read_pickle('./couple_data_without_resample_target')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pred.values, target.values.ravel(), test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# Try TPOT
from tpot import TPOTClassifier

pipeline_optimizer = TPOTClassifier(scoring='f1', cv=5, random_state=42, verbosity=2, n_jobs=-1)
pipeline_optimizer.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipeline_optimizer.export('./tpot_exported_pipeline.py')`
```

Comment: The same script is still running while the CPU utilisation drops...

Comment: Without knowing the details of the script, this question cannot be answered. The likely valid reason is that: the script does some work when it starts, but then just waits later.

Comment: Please clarify what script is doing and the CPU intensive operations. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: and @SaherAhwal